# How to save a worksheet in a different path with a different name

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with multiples worksheets, one of these files I would like to export to a different path I created a macro to do this and it is working pretty fine but I would like to everytime i clicked in the Macro button the file is gonna be saved in that file with a different name. Ex: The First Time I clicked in the button save as xxx1, the second time created a new file called xxx2, is it even possible to do this?

I am going to paste my code below:

```
Sub Macro7()
' Macro7 Macro
    Sheets("Saving").Select
    Sheets("Saving").Copy
    ChDir _
        "C:\Users\L10\Desktop\Rodrigo"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\L10\Desktop\Rodrigo\xxx1.xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

With this macro I created, when I click on the macro button always save in the same file (not as save as)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but you could count your files in the folder and use that as the next file number:

```
Sub Macro7()

    Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\L10\Desktop\Rodrigo"
    path = FolderPath & "\*.xlsx"

    Filename = Dir(path)

    Do While Filename <> ""
        count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

   Sheets("Saving").Select
   Sheets("Saving").Copy
    ChDir _
         FolderPath
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        FolderPath & "\xxx" & count & ".xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfectly worked thank you very much for the code tips, you are the best